# What is this white component in this circuit?

Tags: identification, components

Can't figure out what is this component and also please mention about how to test it?

[image: photo of components on PCB]

Comment: looks like a creamic resistor, but is very small

Comment: Its actually more than 1 inch tall

Comment: I also think it is a resistor. A ceramic case with a (wire wound) resistor cemented inside. I have similar ones but these have square (not rounded) cases. But look the same. Solder it out and measure with a multimeter (ohms measurement).

Comment: There are vertical cement resistors with the same color and texture. But I have not find the cylindrical cement resistor.